# In a .net blazor maui app does the user need to update from the app store if only blazor is updated?

Tags: android, ios, .net, blazor, maui

I'm investigating whether a .net Maui Blazor hybrid is a good fit to update some mobile apps at my company.

Ideally we would love to be able to push updates without the user having to update the app from the ios/android app store.

My question is: once I get my app tested and published, **if I ONLY update the BLAZOR part of my app will this require the user to update the app?**

Side question, is the Blazor part of a Maui/hybrid app server-side blazor or the webassebmly type?

It would be great if I could just push updates without the user having to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Maui Blazor is compatible with webassembly blazor (there is no local web server for server-side apis). It is a type of "Blazor Hybrid Web App".
- It is self-contained in the app bundle; your razor pages become part of that. Therefore, any update requires the app itself to be updated.